# Refresh the top (active) tab with autohotkey

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I have never used it, and after few attempts I feel like i will never get this. I feel this little program has potential but after finding out chrome has multiple child windows i don't think i know what's going on so please help...

I need a script that reloads the page on the current tab of chrome whenever i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> without switching to chrome and then little variation of that key to actually switch and refresh. Like lets say Numpad 1 for just refresh and Numpad 2 for switch and refresh.

Answer (score 6):

Adding on to BGM...

Google Chrome - Hotkeys
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Activates the Google Chrome window

```
WinActivate,ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

Switches to the next tab.

```
ControlSend,,{Ctrl Down}{Tab}{Ctrl Up},ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

Switches to the previous tab.

```
ControlSend,,{Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{Tab}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up},ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

Ctrl+R : Reloads your current page.

```
ControlSend,,{Ctrl Down}r{Ctrl Up},ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

F5 : Reloads your current page.

```
ControlSend,,{F5},ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

Comment: Power to you Joe. +1 for the effort.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Show some code... So that we may assist you properly

Comment: It was like `A:: ControlSend,,{F5},ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is, basically, what you need to do:

1. Create a hotkey to run a sub.
2. Set Chrome as the active window (this will "switch") to Chrome.
3. Send the hotkey for refresh (usually <kbd>F5</kbd>)

If you can scramble a sample script together and post it, I'll help you debug it.

Comment: I signed up to receive the feed for autohotkey.